# How to get a rating value in asp.net mvc4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-routing

I am new asp.net mvc4 with entity frame work, I have designed rating in cshtml file,Pls help me to get a rated value in Controller. Thanks in advance.
This is my cshtml code for rating
{

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index rating</h2>

  <h2>rating</h2>
  @*<form method="post" id="signin" action="@Url.Action("rating", "Rating")">*@
  @if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
  { 
      <form method="post" id="signin" action="@Url.Action("rating", "Rating")">
 <p>
 @DateTime.Now
 </p>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
      <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/rating.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/Styles/rating.css" />
      <script type="text/javascript">
          $(function () {
              $('.rating').rating();
              $('.ratingEvent').rating({ rateEnd: function (v) { $('#result').text(v); } });
          });
      </script>
      <input type="text" class="ratingEvent rating5" @*id="result"*@ value="rating" />
      <div><b id="result">5</b> start(s)</div>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>

  </form>
  }
```

}
This is my Controller code
{

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult rating(int ratedvalue)
        {
            using (var db = new Project.Models.EntitiesContext())
          {

            var value= new Project.Models.Tbl_Rating();
            var rat = db.Tbl_Rating.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Rating == ratedvalue);
            value.Rating = Convert.ToInt32(rat);

            return View();

        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: explain error you are facing

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea about how to get a rated value in Controller,Pls help me out.

Comment: just put name attribute in your `input` and during submit you will get the value in controller as `1 or 2` depending on star selected

Comment: Refer this article http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/114/jQuery-Star-Rating-with-ASP.NET-MVC

Comment: @Nilesh,,The control is not transferring to the controller from cshtml page. When i clicked rating the controller remains in same page. Then how to pass  the value to controller?,,,

Comment: @Vetri can you show your controller code

Comment: @Nilesh I have added my controller code,,pls check it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this

View:

```
 <form method="post" id="signin" action="@Url.Action("rating", "Rating")">
      **YOUR CODE**
  <input type="text" class="ratingEvent rating5" name="rating" value="rating" /> //Add name attribute
  <input type="submit" />         
</form>
```

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult rating(FormCollection form)
  {
     int ratedvalue=form["rating"]
  }
```